# Why was my answer edit undone, and what should I have done instead?

Tags: discussion, answers

Yesterday, I posted [an answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674532/1078151) that as evidenced in the chain of comments, and restated in [How can we make angle brackets more intuitive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117540) due to the angle brackets getting eaten, myself and others were answering based on flawed evidence. After this was pointed out, a very authoritative answer was provided and I edited my answer to be the original text struck out with a note that I had been corrected by someone else. Today, I see that my answer has been re-edited to no longer be struck out and my note that I was wrong has been removed. So, now it looks like I answered incorrectly and just ignored it. I'd rather indicate that my original answer was incorrect and that I'm deferring to a better answer than to just leave my incorrect answer sitting there.

- Why was my edit undone?
- What should I have done instead?

Edit: Just FYI, I did search on both Stack Overflow and here on meta for related posts and didn't see any. Apologies in advance if I missed a related question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Answers crossed `<strike>` are definitely not useful. That's why your answer was rolled back.
2. What should you do / have done?

   - Delete your answer by using the `Delete answer` link, at the bottom of your answer
     Since another excellent answer was already given, this option would be the best choice, in this case. *(or)*
   - Improve your answer by correcting the mistake.
   - Extend the post with a warning that the answer is incorrect, with a number of reasons **if the mistake is subtle**. For example, a frequently made mistake can be pointed out in the answer, so that future readers do not make the same mistake.